# How can i load a image from a server using image id?

Tags: vb.net

Hello i need to know how to load images using image ids in vb.net like localhost/2. I have already set the server but i need to use a text box to enter the id and load the image. Can anyone help me please? Note that i am using a button to load the image after the id has been inputted into the text box. 
This is what i got so far:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = webDownloadImage("http://localhost/", True, "C:\temp.jpg")
End Sub

Public Function webDownloadImage(ByVal Url As String, Optional ByVal saveFile As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal location As String = "C:\") As Image

    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim bytes() As Byte = webClient.DownloadData(Url)
    Dim stream As New IO.MemoryStream(bytes)

    If saveFile Then My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(location, bytes, False)

    Return New System.Drawing.Bitmap(stream)

End Function
```

Comment: Show what you have done so far, please.

Comment: @brcm There i added it

Comment: Just to confirm, you need to append the ID in the url? Example: `ID = 2` and `URL = "http://localhost/2"` ?

Comment: @kaonashi If your gonna comment here please help me otherwise don't post here.

Comment: Just respond properly on my last question, explain your problem so that I can help.

Comment: @kaonashi this is what i need: PictureBox1.Image = webDownloadImage("http://localhost/(TextBox1.Text)", True, "C:\temp.jpg") but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you can do, just append the value of the textbox - `TextBox1.Text` to your URL, just make sure it has a value before you do it.

```
PictureBox1.Image = webDownloadImage("localhost/" & TextBox1.Text, True, "C:\temp.jpg")
```

Comment: Show the code where you tried it, the one you posted does not include the textbox part.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry about that comment i got it working just removed this ;